# Proving $C([0,1])$ is not dense in $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ using an explicit counterexample.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu = $ Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $f: \mathbb [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ defined as:
> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1  & \text{$x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$} \\
> 0 & \text{$x \in [0,1] - \mathbb Q$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> 1. Prove $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$.
> 2. Using the definition of $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}=\inf\{a\in \mathbb R | \mu(\{|f|>a\}) = 0 \}$ show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all continuous functions $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$, $\lVert f-g \rVert_{\infty} \ge \epsilon$.
> 3. Conclude $C([0,1])$ is not dense in $L^{\infty}(\mu)$.

For the first part, since $\mu(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1])=0$ we have $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}=0$ and so $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$.
As for the second part, I'm having trouble using the definition of $\infty$-norm. I understand that the essential supremum is like taking the supremum of a function only over non-null sets, but how can I determine for which $a\in \mathbb R$ the set $\{|f-g|>a\}$  is of measure zero if $g$ is arbitrary?

Comment: Take $g=0$.  $g$ is continuous and $\|f-g\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty=0$.

Comment: The space $C[0,1]$ is complete. Therefore any function $f\in L^\infty(\mu)\setminus C[0,1]$ can serve as an example. Picking up such a function shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This counterexample doesn't seem to work, as $g\equiv 0$ is continuous and $||f-g||_\infty=||f||_\infty=0$.

However, take $f$ defined as $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{$x \in [0,1/2)$} \\
0 & \text{$x \in [1/2,1]$}
\end{cases}$$

which clearly verifies $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$.

Take any continuous function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$. If $|g(1/2)|<1/2$ then $|g(x)|<3/4$ for $x$ in some interval around $1/2$ and thus $||f-g||_\infty\geq 1/4$.  If $|g(1/2)|\geq 1/2$ then $|g(x)|>1/4$ for $x$ in some interval around $1/2$ and thus $||f-g||_\infty\geq 1/4$.

For this reason, taking $\varepsilon=1/4$ there is no continuous function $g$ such that $||f-g||_\infty<\varepsilon$, and from here $C([0,1])$ is not dense in $L^\infty(\mu)$.